# Adding Shiro to the Eclipse java project - no error message at all for diagnosis

Tags: console, shiro

I have just added Shiro to the project, adding two jars to the WEB-INF/lib (shiro-core and shiro-web), customizing the web.xml, and adding shiro.ini in the WEB-INF folder. I have also written an ad hoc menu.jsp with the login form using shiro:guest tags. The problem is that , when I launch the application, and insert the username and password into the form, in order to login, nothing happen and really no message is displayed in the console. So it is difficult for me to do a diagnosis of the problem. What should I do in order to proceed ?

```
web.xml is the following:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>photoalbum</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>chainConfig</param-name>
            <param-value>org/apache/struts/tiles/chain-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>it.univaq.mwt.bcd.photoalbum.common.startup.PhotoAlbumServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.do</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

the shiro.ini is the following

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /index.do
authc.successUrl  = /common/welcome.do
myroles= it.univaq.mwt.bcd.photoalbum.common.shiro.MyRolesAuthorizationFilter 
myRealm = it.univaq.mwt.bcd.photoalbum.common.shiro.MyAuthorizingRealm
securityManager.realms = $myRealm


[users]
#borrower = borrower, borrower
#librarian = librarian, librarian
#masterlibrarian = masterlibrarian, masterlibrarian
#RegisteredUser = RegisteredUser


[roles]
#borrower = *
#librarian = *
#masterlibrarian = *
#RegisteredUser = *

[urls]
/index.do = authc
/logout.do = logout
/common/** = authc, myroles[librarian, masterlibrarian, borrower, RegisteredUser]
/titles/** = authc, myroles[librarian,masterlibrarian, RegisteredUser]
/borrowers/** = authc, myroles[librarian, masterlibrarian, RegisteredUser]
/items/** = authc, myroles[librarian, masterlibrarian, RegisteredUser]
/librarians/** = authc, myroles[masterlibrarian, RegisteredUser]
/items/checkoutitem.do = authc, myroles[borrower]
/items/returntitem.do = authc, myroles[borrower]
```

the menu.jsp is the following:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://shiro.apache.org/tags" prefix="shiro"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/common/welcome.do"><bean:message key="common.title" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <shiro:authenticated>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><bean:message key="menu.home" /><b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>                                <a
                                    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/registered/profile.do">
                                    <bean:message key="menu.profile" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a
                                    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/registered/uploadform.do">
                                    <bean:message key="menu.upload" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <shiro:hasRole name="RegisteredUser">
                        <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/registered/listresource.do"><bean:message key="menu.list" /></a></li>   
                        <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/registered/commentresource.do"><bean:message key="menu.comment" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/registered/gallery.do"><bean:message key="menu.gallery" /></a></li>     
                    </shiro:hasRole>
                    <shiro:hasRole name="Admin">
                </shiro:hasRole>
            <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout.do"><bean:message key="menu.logout" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </shiro:authenticated>

            <shiro:guest>

                <form name="loginform" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index.do" method="post" class="navbar-form navbar-right" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" name="j_username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="j_password">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                        <bean:message key="common.signin" />
                    </button>
                </form>
            </shiro:guest>


        </div>
        <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I also have this two java programs (not by me) that make to work the shiro.ini

```
package it.univaq.mwt.bcd.photoalbum.common.shiro;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import it.univaq.mwt.bcd.photoalbum.business.BusinessException;
import it.univaq.mwt.bcd.photoalbum.business.LibraryBusinessFactory;
import it.univaq.mwt.bcd.photoalbum.business.PhotoAlbumBusinessFactory;
import it.univaq.mwt.bcd.photoalbum.business.SecurityService;
import it.univaq.mwt.bcd.photoalbum.business.model.Role;
import it.univaq.mwt.bcd.photoalbum.business.model.User;

import org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationInfo;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationToken;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.SimpleAuthenticationInfo;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken;
import org.apache.shiro.authz.AuthorizationException;
import org.apache.shiro.authz.AuthorizationInfo;
import org.apache.shiro.authz.Permission;
import org.apache.shiro.authz.SimpleAuthorizationInfo;
import org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthorizingRealm;
import org.apache.shiro.subject.PrincipalCollection;

public class MyAuthorizingRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
        UsernamePasswordToken upToken = (UsernamePasswordToken) token;
        SecurityService service = PhotoAlbumBusinessFactory.getInstance().getSecurityService();

        User user = null;
        try {
            user = service.authenticate(upToken.getUsername());
        } catch (BusinessException idEx) {
            throw new AuthenticationException(idEx);
        } 

        if (user == null) {
            throw new AuthenticationException("Login name [" + upToken.getUsername() + "] not found!");
        }

        return new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(user, user.getPassword(), getName());
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
        Set<String>         roles           = new HashSet<String>();
        Set<Permission>     permissions     = new HashSet<Permission>();
        Collection<User>    principalsList  = principals.byType(User.class);

        if (principalsList.isEmpty()) {
            throw new AuthorizationException("Empty principals list!");
        }
        SecurityService service = PhotoAlbumBusinessFactory.getInstance().getSecurityService();
        //LOADING STUFF FOR PRINCIPAL 
        for (User userPrincipal : principalsList) {
            try {

                User user = service.authenticate(userPrincipal.getUsername());

                Set<Role> userRoles = user.getRoles();
                for (Role r : userRoles) {
                    roles.add(r.getName());
                }
            } catch (BusinessException idEx) { //userManger exceptions
                throw new AuthorizationException(idEx);
            } 
        }
        //THIS IS THE MAIN CODE YOU NEED TO DO !!!!
        SimpleAuthorizationInfo info = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo(roles);
        info.setRoles(roles); //fill in roles 
        info.setObjectPermissions(permissions); //add permissions (MUST IMPLEMENT SHIRO PERMISSION INTERFACE)

        return info;
    }

}
```

and the following :

```
package it.univaq.mwt.bcd.photoalbum.common.shiro;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

import org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject;
import org.apache.shiro.util.CollectionUtils;
import org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authz.AuthorizationFilter;

public class MyRolesAuthorizationFilter extends AuthorizationFilter {

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    public boolean isAccessAllowed(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, Object mappedValue) throws IOException {

        Subject subject = getSubject(request, response);
        String[] rolesArray = (String[]) mappedValue;

        if (rolesArray == null || rolesArray.length == 0) {
            //no roles specified, so nothing to check - allow access.
            return true;
        }

        Set<String> roles = CollectionUtils.asSet(rolesArray);

        for (String role : roles) {
            if (subject.hasRole(role)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

My only doubt is if these two java programs fits for my application (I used these two java programs in another java project and they worked)! Please help me ! Thanks.

Comment: You can start by sharing the files you changed. Without any additional info, we cannot help you.

Comment: The shiro.ini is the following :

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are the victim of the following bug:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-467

Authentication exceptions which could happen in your custom realm get swallowed by shiro.

There is a workaround to get the exception thrown which worked for us. If you can get a hold of the securityManager object somewhere in a startup method (we use spring, so we use a configuration class, but you might be able to use a servlet context listener or something like that). 
On the security manager, register an authentication listener like so:

```
    AbstractAuthenticator abstractAuthenticator = (AbstractAuthenticator) securityManager.getAuthenticator();
    abstractAuthenticator.getAuthenticationListeners().add(new AuthenticationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AuthenticationToken token, AuthenticationInfo info) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(AuthenticationToken token, AuthenticationException ae) {
            if (ae.getCause() != null) {
                //log exception or do ae.printStackTrace(), we log it:
                LOG.error("Problem during authenticating {}", token, ae);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLogout(PrincipalCollection principals) {
        }
    });
```